# Recursive Reminder in SharePoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, reminder

I have a requirement where I have to create a workflow that will send the recursive email. I have "Date of visit" date column where I will set some date then   email will send to monthly adding 1 month to "Date of visit", we can change date as well accordingly it will pick new date  `" ex: "Date of Visit" 12/18/2019 email will send on 1/18/2020, then 2/18/2020 so on.."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create SharePoint 2013 platform workflow, this workflow can loop and will follow this pattern:

[image]

The workflow has a Loop, and inside of the loop, an email Action and a Pause Action. This example loops forever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Pause until** action in the workflow to send the reminder email every month.

Here is the basic idea of the workflow.

1. **Pause until Date –** set the date to the NextReminderTime field of the current item.
2. **Send an Email –** send the email as required.
3. **Update List Item –** set the date in your calculated column for the nextReminderDate

Reference: https://threewill.com/sending-reminder-emails-using-sharepoint-designer-workflows/